# Excel: Copy specific columns of a row to new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a MAIN worksheet where I enter the following:

```
Name    5AM  8AM  3PM  Room  Comment
John     X              1A    Blah    
Peter    X    X    X    2B    Some Blah
Ann           X         3C    Some more Blah
```

Aside from worksheet **MAIN**, I have 3 others according to the time. In other words, the other worksheet names are **5AM**, **8AM**, and **3PM**. Basically, I am trying to fill each worksheet given the corresponding time marked with an **X**.

So Worksheet **5AM** should have the following.

```
Name    Room  Comment
John     1A    Blah    
Peter    2B    Some Blah
```

Worksheet **8AM** should have the following.

```
Name    Room  Comment
Peter    2B    Some Blah
Ann      3C    Some more Blah
```

Worksheet **3PM** should have the following.

```
Name    Room  Comment
Peter    2B   Some Blah
```

I started with creating some code in the MAIN worksheet using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Sheets("10AM").Range("A1").End(xlup).Offset(1, 0)

End Sub
```

but it's not really working out.

Comment: I added a post which will do what you want(or almost). But I do not recommend using events for this. I hope that post gets you started. It still needs to be improved since there are still a lot of hardcoded stuff. so goodluck.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet, fiveAM As Worksheet, eightAM As Worksheet, ninePM As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim lrow As Long, i As Integer
Dim shname As String
Dim columntocopy As Range, rowtocopy As Range, rngtocopy As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("MAIN")
Set fiveAM = wb.Sheets("5AM")
Set eightAM = wb.Sheets("8AM")
Set ninePM = wb.Sheets("9PM")
Set columntocopy = ws.Range("A:A,E:E,F:F")

With ws
    lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 0 To 2
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        shname = .Range("B1").Offset(0, i).Value
        .Range("B1:B" & lrow).Offset(0, i).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="X"
        Set rowtocopy = .Range("A1:A" & lrow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        Set rngtocopy = Intersect(rowtocopy, columntocopy)
        rngtocopy.Copy
        Select Case shname
        Case "5AM": fiveAM.Range("A" & fiveAM.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Case "8AM": eightAM.Range("A" & eightAM.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Case "9PM": ninePM.Range("A" & ninePM.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End Select
    Next
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I assumed your data in each sheet starts at `Column A`.
Tried and tested.
I leave the further testing to you.